# Invalid / Unknown namespace in Air application with Air Native Extension (ANE)

Tags: apache-flex, air, namespaces, flash-builder, ane

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 with Air SDK 16.0 (I've followed this tuto : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html to update the SDK and generate my ANE)

I'm developing an Air Native Extension which is compiled just fine but when I try to test it on a Flex Mobile application

I updated the application descriptor to match the Air SDK :

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0">
```

But I got this error when I run it :

```
Invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0
```

Or when I export it :

```
error 102: Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0
```

I really don't know what is happening here, can you help me ?

Comment: That error suggests that you overlaid the standalone Air SDK on Flex, which won't work.  Double-check that you have the right file; on the Air download page, you need to use the tiny text link below the big "Download" buttons.

Comment: Yeah I did overlay it following the tuto (with ASC for the ANE dev and without it for the rest) In fact I'm picking the good versions from here : https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html (AIR 16 in my case, since I don't want the last version)

Comment: Definitely suggests you haven't overlaid the AIR 16 SDK correctly.

Comment: On that page, you'll need to download the files under " Adobe AIR 16 SDK downloads" -- if you got the files from "Adobe AIR 16 SDK and Compiler downloads" by mistake, that would cause this error.

Comment: Make sure you have this AIR version set to compile both your ANE code and your app under Project properties > Flex compiler > Flex SDK Version

Answer (score 0):

I just start all over from the beginning, uninstalling Flash Builder and updating the SDK : it's working now so I guess I messed up somewhere... 
Thanks for all your insights though!